# firefox returns SSL_ERROR_BAD_MAC_READ

Tags: apache, firefox, ibmhttpserver

I've a strange behaviour with firefox browser.
I've an old  IBM http server 7.0.0.35 when I call it with firefox in https it returns this error:  SSL_ERROR_BAD_MAC_READ . with internet explorer I can see the site correctly.

to better investigate I've export the certificate and key in another apache asf (2.4) and it works always, even with firefox.
so I assume is not a certificate problem but something between firefox and the http server. any firefox browser on any client has this error with this webserver.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

7.0.0.35 is no longer fit for any purpose, it's no wonder a TLS client from 2019 cannot talk to an implementation from 2014.

Comment: thanks for reply! I know, but we are in a particular environment and at now is not possible to upgrade. my question is which reason could determine this? chiper, etc... ?

Comment: Probably something like no support for extended master secret

Comment: Thanks, the ihs was 7.0.0.0, I've upgrade it to 7.0.0.41 and now it works.